# Rails loading both app/assets and public/assets in development mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

If I precompile my assets locally, then the precompiled assets (public/assets) are served in addition to the unprecompiled assets (app/assets). I have tried adding

```
config.serve_static_assets = false
```

to my development.rb. The other asset configuration parameters in development.rb are:

```
config.assets.compress = false
config.assets.debug = true
```

Of course I can delete the public/assets folder, but I don't want to have to precompile the assets before every push -- that's why I started precompiling locally in the first place. Any ideas on how I can get Rails to only serve the nonprecompiled assets?

Comment: Setting server_static_assets to false should be enough. Can you try to clear your browser's cache to see if it changes anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution is probably to store your precompiled assets in different places for production and development. Leave them under `public/assets` for production, and set a different path for development like that:

```
# config/environments/development.rb
config.assets.prefix = '/dev/assets'
```

As you don't want to precompile your assets for development, that folder will be empty, and you'll end up loading only the assets from `app/assets` in development. And production will keep using the ones from `public/assets`.